# Not able to to delete file with drwx--S--- permission

Tags: permissions, delete, chmod, rm, android-emulator

We are not able to delete file because of special permission drwx--S---. I have tried command   chmod g -s filenameion but we cant use root user. SO is there anyway to delete

Answer (score 1):

It is not the `S` (setgid) attribute that is preventing you from deleting the file or directory.

> is there anyway to delete

It depends.

You are dealing with a directory (folder). One reason why you cannot delete the directory may be because you use the `rm <name>`.  That does not work for a directory. ⟶ Use `rmdir <name>` (for this the directory must be empty), or `rm -r <name>` (can be done on a directory that is not yet empty).

Another reason why you cannot delete the directory might be that you are not the owner. ⟶ Sorry, you will need to ask someone with permissions to remove the directory.